# How to get sound from java-based services

Tags: java, web-services, apache-flex, blazeds

I have a Java-based server side and a flex client side using Spring BlazeDS Integration. It works fine, but I want to get sound from server side recently.

I followed this [BlazeDS mapping doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html), it says when Java return a Byte[], it will be converted to ByteArray which I want. So I handle the MP3 file by ByteArrayOutputStream, convert it to Byte[] and return it back to front-end, but the value that Actionscript gets turns to be null value.

```
public Byte[] sayHello() {
    Byte[] ba = null;

    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                "D:/e/Ryan Adams - I Wish You Were Here.mp3");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
        ba = new Byte[byteArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
            ba[i] = Byte.valueOf(byteArray[i]);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ba;
}
```

The ActionScript code:

```
<s:RemoteObject id="ro" destination="helloWorldService" fault="handleFault(event)">
    <s:channelSet>
        <s:ChannelSet>
            <s:AMFChannel uri="/flexspring/messagebroker/amf"/>
        </s:ChannelSet>
    </s:channelSet>
</s:RemoteObject>

...

private function loaded():void {
    var bArr:ByteArray = ro.sayHello() as ByteArray;
    l.text = "" + (bArr == null);
}

...

<s:Label id="l" text=""/>
```

And it says "true". Does anyone have any idea what's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that all flex calls over a BlazeDS are async. So, `ro.SomeMethod()` doesn't return immediately, it queues it up and then does callbacks as necessary.

Here's an example of something that works Note that I've never sent `byte[]` over a BlazeDS connection, but I don't see why it wouldn't work --- as J_A_X suggests, you probably want to stream the sound, rather than sending the whole thing at once.

Anyway - here's the example:

```
public function loaded():void
{
   var token:AsyncToken = ro.sayHello();
   token.addResponder(new mx.rpc.Responder(result, fault));
   // ...Code continues to execute...
}

public function result(event:ResultEvent):void
{
   // The byte[] is in event.result
   var bArr:ByteArray = event.result as ByteArray;
}

public function fault(event:FaultEvent):void 
{
   // Something went wrong (maybe the server on the other side went AWOL) 
}
```

Comment: That's really helpful, now the sound goes well. I have one last question, how to play two or more sounds one by one.

Comment: You should post a new question for that. I've never tried to play sound in Flash. Please accept the answer you find most helpful (click the empty check mark next to it.)

Answer (score 1):

You can return the sound bytes through a web service.  After you got the bytes, you can add it to a Sound object and play that.  The only problem is that since it's a web service, the client will have to load all the bytes before it can play.  If you want to stream the sound, you'll need a streaming server like FMS or Wowza (I recommend the latter).

Comment: Can you make an example on this? How Java transforms a sound file into bytes. Should I use java.io package? Where to store the bytes, in an array or what? Then how ActionScript transforms it back. And it's similar when it's an image or a video, right?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to do the work for you.  I answered your question by giving you the path to go down.  You're the one that needs to do the research and do it.  If you got more questions, post the code that you've tried and we can help out.

Comment: You should answer the question, rather than giving some vague answer that doesn't really address the problem he's experiencing.